# Find wifi enabled devices [stations] around

Tags: wifi, wireless, aircrack-ng

Imagine this situation that there are some smartphones and computer around with their WiFi adapter (wireless adapters) on, but not necessary connected to a network.

Is there a way to look the MAC addresses via a Linux machine?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: This seems more like a question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Disconnected clients aren't always silent. In fact, more often than not, clients send out directed and broadcast probe requests searching for access points they have connected to previously, thus revealing their MAC addresses which can be displayed through airodump-ng or by filtering capture packets in Wireshark to display probe requests.
This is the suitable Wireshark filter:

```
wlan.fc.type_subtype eq 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but i'll have a go anyway.

Wifi enabled devices usually send probe requests to try to find Access points they previously have been connected to, even when they are nowhere near them.

If you're using backtrack/kali linux, try this:

Create a wireless adapter alias running in monitor mode (assuming your adapter name is wlan0):

`airmon-ng start wlan0`

Start scanning for devices and access points:

`airodump-ng mon0`

The access points will be listed first with their Mac addresses under "BSSID", followed by the devices which will have their MAC addresses listed under "STATION" and a "not associated" flag under "BSSID" if they aren't connected to an access point.

Comment: This will not work if the network was forgot after connecting once.

Comment: @haccks True, but the default setting for most devices is to remember and connect to previous AP:s. You would have to "forget" all previous AP:s for this not to work.